# How to turn google chrome caches off completely

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I've tried everything I can think of.

Even tried to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then click the "*Disable cache*" under network, but nothing works.

Do I really have to clear it my self, every now and then or can I just turn it off completely somehow?

Comment: Does Chrome still save caches when under Incognito mode?

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing that makes you think it is still caching?

Answer (score 5):

The Developer Tools section has an option to disable cache. In the dev tools window, click the gear icon in the bottom right corner, and under Network, check "disable cache."

I found this in version 14.0.835.35 beta.

Say thanks ! =)

Comment: Hi, looks like this answer is (partially) outdated – you actually need to keep dev tools open for this to work (apparently). Any idea if there a current solution?

Answer (score 4):

Disabling the cache in the Developer Tools only disables the cache while DevTools is open. While this may be what some people are looking for, you can completely disable the cache by:

1) entering the command prompt

2) enter "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" (to change the directory to where Google Chrome is stored)

3) enter "chrome.exe --media-cache-size=1 --disk-cache-size=1" to minimize the size of both the caches, effectively completely disabling the cache

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disk-cache-size=1

In actuality I want an option to completely disable the cache, to use the memory for IO instead of my disk (which would make load time 10x faster too!) but I don't think chrome or any browser for that matter has that option yet.